# how to call a function within an if statement (vba)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I am trying to call a function within my if statement. The function is called classyear and is just after the if. I am trying to run through a timetable and see what classes belong to each year. so if it ends in a 1 it will be counted. Does anyone know how I would go about calling the function? Any help is appreciated

```
Public Sub time() 
Dim rgTimeTable As Range, rgClass As Range, counter As Integer

Set rgTimeTable = Range("B3, N11")

For Each rgClass In rgTimeTable
If rgClass.Value = classyear Then counter = counter + 1     ' classyear is the function 

Next rgClass
MsgBox test     ' also a function 

End Sub
```

EDIT 
Code for the function i am trying to call

```
Public Function classyear(class As String) As Integer

Dim yr As String

yr = Right(class, 1)
If IsNumeric(yr) Then classyear = yr Else classyear = 0

End Function
```

Comment: We need to see the code for `classyear` too. If it's a sub then nothing will be returned, if it's a function that isn't returning anything then it will cause the same problem

Comment: @MacroMan i add the function, i just get some error when trying to run it

Comment: You need to pass a string argument to `Classyear` which you aren't at the moment.

Comment: classyear is an integer. You may compare it with another value in just the way you have done in your code. What problem is your code giving you? If you just want to run the code, place the cursor anywhere in the procedure and press F5. Make sure the correct sheet is active at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `classyear` function takes a string input, so you need to give it one. Something like:

```
If CInt(rgClass.Value) = classyear("Year1") Then counter = counter + 1
```

---

Also you can neaten up your `classyear` function:

```
Public Function classyear(class As String) As Integer
    On Error Resume Next 'if error classyear will return 0
    classyear = CInt(Right(class, 1))
End Function
```

Comment: you could omit the `On Error GoTo 0` statement since error handling automatically gets reset to the caller sub one upon leaving the function

Comment: and more, if you knew there's a error handling in the caller sub that would properly handle any function error, then you could omit all `On Error ...` statement inside the function and have the calling Sub go to its deputed `Label`

Answer (score 0):

You can call a Sub inside if block like:

(Use function if you want to return some value else use Sub)

```
if (...)

   classyear() '<--Calling the Sub defined below

End if 



Private Sub classyear()
  .
  .
End Sub
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: that doesnt seem to be working for me, maybe i am just doing it wrong im not sure